# Sounds recaptured from the air

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

In this story, a scientist reasoned that every sound that had ever been generated in the Earth's atmosphere was still reverberating, albeit very faintly. He invented a machine that would isolate and magnify scraps of sound from yesteryear. And that's all I remember. It must have been published in an English-language anthology before 1970, and it was likely in the 19th century or early 20th century, because it is now understood that Brownian motion represents a natural limit on how faint a sound can be before it is randomized.

Comment: Are you sure it was science fiction? This reminds me strikingly of the bit in the Discworld novels about the Listeners, who are trying to listen for "what it was the Creator said when He made the universe".

Comment: Shades of Blish's "Beep."  I found a story from *Weird Tales*, 1939, that refers to the idea without actually using it, so it may have been used elsewhere in that era.

Comment: @user14111 and others: I read a good bit of early SF in the 1960s, but almost entirely in books, only rarely magazines. My family did subscribe to non-SF magazines such as the _Saturday Evening Post_, and I bought a few issues of an obscure magazine that reprinted early 20th-century SF. I haven't read the Discworld novels. I have read "Beep", which has all the Dirac (compare ansible) messages that were ever sent, or will be sent, rendered simultaneously. Interesting idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could this be "[The Automaton Ear](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?914621)" by Florence McLandburgh? This short story was first published in 1873, as you suspected in the nineteenth century, and was included in an anthology, "[The Automaton Ear, and Other Sketches](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?270556)" in 1876 (so indeed,"before 1970" by some margin!), and more recently in 2015 in "[The Feminine Future: Early Science Fiction by Women Writers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?521526)".

The story deals with a scientist who builds an elaborate amplifying device, essentially a souped-up "ear trumpet", to pick up sounds from events that occurred millennia ago:

> As a particle of the atmosphere is never lost, so sound is never lost.
> A strain of music or a simple tone will vibrate in the air forever and
> ever, decreasing according to a fixed ratio. The diffusion of the
> agitation extends in all directions, like the waves in a pool, but the
> ear is unable to detect it beyond a certain point. It is well known
> that some individuals can distinguish sounds which to others under
> precisely similar circumstances are wholly lost. Thus the fault is not
> in the sound itself, but in our organ of hearing, and a tone once in
> existence is always in existence.

The short story is available as a free ebook [here](https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=SpDUAAAAMAAJ&pg=GBS.PA6&hl=en_GB).

Comment: The only familiar part is the quotation, which apparently the author made up but not from whole cloth. Was she inspired by Charles Babbage of computer fame? From his 9th Bridgewater Treatise (1837): "The air itself is one vast library, on whose pages are for ever written all that man has ever said or woman whispered. There, in their mutable but unerring characters, mixed with the earliest, as well as with the latest sighs of mortality, stand for ever recorded, vows unredeemed, promises unfulfilled, perpetuating in the united movements of each particle, the testimony of man's changeful will."

Comment: I am hesitant about this, because the only familiar part IS the quotation -- but in all truth that does seem familiar, so I'm going to accept this answer, with my thanks. I can't imagine where I might have read it, but the ISFDB is hardly complete. Additional thanks for providing a link to the story; that certainly helped.